# mpd listening on port 6600

Tags: connection, mpd

I find on netstat that mpd is listening on port 6600.

I play all my media files on VLC. I don't remember installing this, and its not in my startup applications.

Is mpd even needed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

mpd is the [Music Player Daemon](http://mpd.wikia.com/wiki/Music_Player_Daemon_Wiki), and should not be needed by VLC. It should be safe to uninstall with `sudo apt-get remove mpd`.